# Verify table type is correct from C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sql-server-2008

I've created a few table types in my database to be used as stored procedure parameters. These correspond  to real database tables, so if they're out of sync there'll be a problem. I'd like to add a unit test that looks at the two and fails if they are different, but I'm not sure where to start.

I don't know if there's a recommended way to do this - I was going to try to somehow pull out the column information, loop through it and fail the test if they're different, but it seems a bit fiddly.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by table types?

Are you looking to compare two Tables within a Database?

Or are you trying to compare data that will only exist on the C# side of things?

Or are you trying to compare a set of data that exists on C# to a Table that exists within a Database?

Comment: this is what I'm doing:
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE
( [Column definitions...] )
It's a mirror of my actual MyTable table, which I can use in bulk updates to pass as a table-valued parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). What I want to do is write a test in C# that compares MyTableType to MyTable, column by column. I guess it would be quite similar to comparing two actual tables.

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about table structure (column names and column types), not necessarily data, right?

Comment: @Tim yes, table structure. I want to ensure that the TYPE and the underlying TABLE have the same columns with the same properties (data type, null/not null, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008, take a look at the `sys.tables`, `sys.table_types` and `sys.columns` system tables.

In one of my databases I have a table type called `candidateRoutes` and a physical (real) table called `RouteArea`

The following two queries:

```
select sys.columns.* from sys.table_types join sys.columns on sys.columns.object_id = sys.table_types.type_table_object_id where sys.table_types.name = 'candidateRoutes'
select sys.columns.* from sys.tables join sys.columns on sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id where sys.tables.name = 'RouteArea'
```

return:

```
object_id  name     column_id  system_type_id  user_type_id  max_length  precision  scale  collation_name  is_nullable  is_ansi_padded    is_rowguidcol  is_identity  is_computed  is_filestream  is_replicated  is_non_sql_subscribed  is_merge_published  is_dts_replicated  is_xml_document  xml_collection_id  default_object_id  rule_object_id  is_sparse  is_column_set
215671816  RouteId  1           56              56            4          10         0      NULL            0            0                 0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
215671816  Area     2          240             130           -1           0         0      NULL            0            0                 0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
```

and

```
object_id   name       column_id  system_type_id  user_type_id  max_length  precision  scale  collation_name  is_nullable  is_ansi_padded  is_rowguidcol  is_identity  is_computed  is_filestream  is_replicated  is_non_sql_subscribed  is_merge_published  is_dts_replicated  is_xml_document  xml_collection_id  default_object_id  rule_object_id  is_sparse  is_column_set
1675153013  RouteId    1          127             127            8          19         0      NULL            0            0               0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
1675153013  ValidFrom  2           61              61            8          23         3      NULL            0            0               0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
1675153013  ValidTo    3           61              61            8          23         3      NULL            1            0               0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
1675153013  Line       4          240             130           -1           0         0      NULL            0            0               0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
1675153013  Area       5          240             130           -1           0         0      NULL            1            0               0              0            0            0              0              0                      0                   0                  0                0                  0                  0               0          0
```

so you could perhaps do something like this:

```
with
    TableType as
        (select name, user_type_id, max_length, precision from sys.columns where object_id = (select type_table_object_id from sys.table_types where name = 'candidateRoutes')),
    PhysicalTable as
        (select name, user_type_id, max_length, precision from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'RouteArea'))
    select * from TableType full join PhysicalTable
        on TableType.name = PhysicalTable.name
    where TableType.name is null
       or PhysicalTable.name is null
       or TableType.user_type_id <> PhysicalTable.user_type_id
       or TableType.max_length   <> PhysicalTable.max_length
       or TableType.precision    <> PhysicalTable.precision
```

but including `scale, collation_name, is_nullable`, etc., to find all columns that do *not* match. In my case, I get:

```
name     user_type_id  max_length  precision  name       user_type_id  max_length  precision
RouteId  56            4           10         RouteId    127           8           19
NULL     NULL          NULL        NULL       ValidFrom  61            8           23
NULL     NULL          NULL        NULL       ValidTo    61            8           23
NULL     NULL          NULL        NULL       Line       130           -1          0
```

If no rows are returned, the type and the table are the same.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. Your last query's where clause - why is it 'where TableType.name is null...'? Doesn't that return 0 rows if any the columns have names? Looks like a great first step to what I want, though

Comment: @Alex: I have done a `full join` on `TableType` and `PhysicalTable`, so that all column names that exist in `TableType` will be show, even if there is no corresponding column in `PhysicalTable`, and vice versa. The two checks for `name is null` then limit the results to columns that only exist in one table or the other. For example, `ValidFrom` exists in `PhysicalTable`, but does _not_ exist in `TableType`, therefore `TableType.name` is null. If you used only those two conditions in the where clause, you would basically see all columns present in either table but missing in the other ...

Comment: ... the remaining conditions in the where clause include all columns that do exist in _both_ tables, but have differing types.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks, I'll probably just created a stored proc and call that from C# for my unit test.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, with C#, you'll have to dump the data from both tables into seperate DataSets, then loop through and compare.  That would be such a resource hog though, and will most likely yield very undesirable performance if you have thousands of records.

Do you have to do it in C#?  Why don't you do the comparison in SQL and return a bool of the results (true, if everything is the same, false if there was a difference)?

But if you must do it in .NET, have you tried looking into F#?  I've been doing a bit of reading, and it looks like F# might be a performance improvement on top of C# for this kind of data analysis.

Here's an article that may help you with F# and SQL.
http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx

Or, you can look into LINQ (sorry, I'm inexperienced with it), it may be the answer to what you're looking for.
http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx

Comment: +1 As both you and Gavin have suggested, I'm trying to create a stored proc that will run on the SQL server and then return a success/failure to my C# code